# How to define a numbering system clearly and succintly

Tags: terminology

I'm attempting to write a definition of an ordering scheme, and can't find the correct wording.

The ordering should allow for different types of numbering systems, such as:
Item1, Item1a, Item2, Item3, Item4a, Item4b, etc.
Item01, Item02, Item03, etc
Item0100a, Item0101, etc

I don't believe this is called numeric sequencing, b/c letter suffixes are allowed.  Can anyone help with the proper phrasing of this?

I'd like to write something like "Lists are sequenced numerically, with an optional letter suffix".  However, that seems so wordy and awkward.  Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Are letter suffixes only used in certain circumstances? If they are, you could break the sentence up to discuss the basic numbering and the times to use letters.

Comment: Frankly, your final sentence is the best you can do.  You could define the concept of and "Item ID" then define it as "Item" + number code + optional single letter suffix.  I'm not sure what rule you have for when to have or not have leading 0s in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Ordered alphanumerically (numbers followed by alphabets)

You may or may not mention the bracket and its contents because after seeing the list, people themselves will understand the order.

Alphanumeric means using both letters and numbers.

Comment: Alphanumeric sorting would put 0100a before item 1.

Comment: But alphanumeric does mean using numbers and letters. That was all I meant. And yeah, it sure would put 0100a before 1, maybe because 0 comes before 1. see.. :-)

Comment: The system of sorting 01 before 1 (and 10 before 2) is commonly called _lexicographical_ order.

Answer (score 0):

It's normally called a [*collation sequence*](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_61/db2/rbafzsortsequence.htm) (or *collating sequence* or *sort sequence*), not an "ordering scheme".

Assuming the actual characters **Item** aren't part of the "identity/key values" (or are a "constant" within *every* value), you could specify OP's example by...

> *The collation sequence is numeric component followed by letter suffix*
>    (or more simply, *suffix within numeric component*)

It might be worth calling it a ***smart*** collation sequence, to emphasise the fact that *any number of digits* (including leading zeros) may be present in the numeric component, so a sorted list could contain, for example,...

> ItemX  (comes *first*, because a non-existent numeric component is treated as zero)
>   Item1
>   Item1a
>   Item1b
>   Item00002 (irrelevant leading zeros ignored)
>   Item2a
>   ...

There are many more potentially relevant aspects to such "smart" sequences - for example, you'd very probably want to compare any alpha suffixes on a case-insensitive basis.